# Is it possible to set a random number generator seed to get reproducible training?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I would like to re-run training with fewer epochs to stop with the same state it had at that point in the earlier training.

I see that `tf.initializers` take a seed argument. `tf.layers.dropout` does as well but 1.2.7 reports "Error: Non-default seed is not implemented in Dropout layer yet: 1". But even without dropout are there other sources of randomness? And can those be provided with a seed?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reproductible training by setting the weights default value. These default value are randomly generated at the beginning of the training.

To set the value of the weights the property `kernerInitializer` of the layer object parameter can be used.

Another way to set the weights is to call `setWeights` on the model passing as arguments the weights values

Also `shuffle` in `model.fit` parameter property is set to true by default. It has to be set to `false` to prevent the training data to be shuffled at each epoch.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and I still got different results from FIT. I recently learned that FIT calls shuffle by default so I just tried adding shuffle: false to the FIT configuration and it became reproducible. Also there are other functions that should take optional seed arguments like tf.util.shuffle

Comment: Yes shuffle value is true by default. See my edited answer